# Performance of programming languages and frameworks

Tags: c++, performance, python, mmo, pygame

I want to program an online 2D MMORPG with graphics like in [this game](http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/). Since I develop in javascript and python mainly I chose python for my first games and the game library pygame which is pretty straightforward and awesome. But since many people go for c++, c# etc. I wonder if I still could achieve what I want to with python. Is anybody experienced with performance with python and pygame in cases like this? should I rather go for c++? Should I use a combination of python and C, or maybe even python and c++?

Comment: I don't think that the language really matters as long as your game framework is good enough for what you are doing. You didn't mention which platform you are targeting. You should just pick the language you know or the one you want to practice. After compiling all the languages are the same set of commands, it doesn't matter, language is just for the programmer

Comment: @Shiro At first I target Windows Computers. I just thought that I might have performance problems if I would go for python and pygame

Comment: Since you seem like a beginner, I doubt you will build something more than 500 people will play at the same time. In that case it doesn't really matter what you use. When a lot of people at the same time are playing though, you will run into some performance issues which would need to be solved more low level. That's why most people that create MMO's use C++, it's one of the most low level languages there are, while python is a very high level language

Comment: @Dries I dream big so I expect even more than 500 people :P So I definitely should go for c++?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi Yes, I think you should use C++. Since you're not used to c++ you will have a hard time figuring out how to create an MMO. Only learning c++ is nothing, getting your networking to work is such a massive task. Try making a simple multiplayer game (1v1) in c++ and then reconsider creating an MMO. Good luck :)

Comment: @Dries sounds like it's uber difficult :D So there is no chance in going with python and pygame :P ?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi I guess you can. Search for some networking libraries in python. Still, building the whole architecture for your game will be very hard. I would definitely NOT recommend doing this when you're a beginner.

Comment: I just build a basic game in pygame with collision detection and pacman in java in school. What would you recommend doing as a beginner then :D ? I would love to just try things out

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @Dries. I am curious of how many of those people who post everyday about "How can I make a 3D FPS/MMORPG" actually ends up doing anything remotely close in difficulty. Makes achievable goals first. Multiplayer aspect in the make makes it a lot more complicated. Try making a tic tac toe online game see if you can do that, then aim higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to this question and to most of the comments.

Try making some other games first. Since you are a beginner, creating a multiplayer tic-tac-toe (as Shiro suggested) will be hard enough. Even if you can manage to create that creating an MMO is a massive task that most of us, and definitely the beginners, will underestimate.

For example: how will you track player movement on other clients, if you're going to do PVP how are you going to send messages so that the other player knows he's been hit. What about, connecting and disconnecting to servers. Will you be creating a Peer-to-peer game, will it be a server-client architecture (with a dedicated server). How will you manage lag and hackers? This and many other questions will arise, which you will probably not think of when you start this.

If you want to continue doing this, create a simple chat system using python first. (you can do this with telnet, which is included in the basic installation of python). If you can manage that, create a VERY simple 2-player game. If you can manage that, go on to creating a game where people can connect to a main pc (p2p host or dedicated server) and see if you can make the players move and make the server send that information to all other connected clients.

TL;DR: It's great that you want to try this but slow down, think about it, realise that this is not just "connecting pc's and I'm done".

Comment: It is really awesome that you mentioned some milestones which I have to achieve. I will try all that stuff out :D thank you very much :)